# Из 2 списков составить 3, в котором буду все неповторяющиеся элементы этих списков

Tags: swi-prolog

Дано 2 списка [9,9,5,7,7,7][1,2,9,6,6,8],на выходе должен получиться список из  элементов, которые присутствуют только в одном из списков, т.е. должно получиться [5,7,7,7,1,2,6,6,8].